# Why is Format of output data grayed out on Save As dialog for Rectify?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, georeferencing

I started georeferencing and I could not save my new "rectify" file, I don't know if is because of the raster or I did something wrong.

Then I find out that my control layer is not accurate, it doesn't match to other shapefiles in the same geodatabase (same projected coordinate reference), neither with a basemap.

How do I activate the Format of output data option on the Save As dialog for Rectify to make sure that I have an accurate control layer?

Comment: "I started georeferencing"  in what application?

Comment: @Mapperz probably in arcgis, theres a georeferencing toolbar

Comment: @U2ros QGIS, SAGA, Idrisi, ERDAS, MapInfo, MapMaker, TNTmips etc all also have georeferncing capabilities, to name but a few other GIS packages.  It might be ArcGIS, but then again it might not, so we need the OP to be specific before the question can be answered for their situation.

Comment: There are many answers for this question in several software. I suggest a search for georeferncing.

Comment: @Mapperz, it's ArcGis 10.0. I will correct my "control" layer with an Esri imaginery, then try to georeference. But I am afraid I wont be able to save my "Rectify" (in the dialog where you save, the selection of type of data is in gray) and I dont know why, besides the fact that my control points were not balanced.

Comment: added tag arcgis-10.0 makes it easier for users to find arcgis questions on GIS-SE

Comment: Thanks, @Mapperz, it's my first time in this site... no wonder!

Comment: Hi According to your question I think you are trying to Geo-reference raster image in ArcMap so Please check following tutorial http://blogs.library.duke.edu/data/2011/11/14/arcgis-tutorial-georeferencing-imagery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Save As dialog opened by Rectify from the Georeferencing pulldown on the Georeferencing toolbar there is a field called Output Location that confuses many people.

On that dialog make sure you do NOT try to enter the Output Image name - just select a folder.  Then you should be able to enter an output image name in the Name field and choose its Format.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out complete & step by step tutorial (contains how to Geo-reference raster image in ArcGIS)

Details: Click [here](http://blogs.library.duke.edu/data/2011/11/14/arcgis-tutorial-georeferencing-imagery/)

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question.